# CakePdf - Engine not loaded

Tags: cakephp

I have installed CakePdf plugin for cakephp as outlined in the readme file on GitHub. I am getting an error saying the engine iisnt loaded. I have tried all 3 engines that come with the plugin. Anyone else have this issue and find a solution? Rhanks

Comment: Sorry I'm not near my code at the moment but I have set it up as per the sample here: https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf

Answer (score 2):

http://www.slideshare.net/jellehenkens/building-php-documents-with-cakepdf-cakefest-2012

Here is a slideshow how to install the plugin,
To load the engine use this in bootstrap.php

```
Configure::write('CakePdf', array(
        'engine' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',

       'pageSize'=>'A4',

        'orientation' => 'landscape',

    ));
```

Go to your controller en use in your public function view or index this:

```
$this -> pdfConfig = array (
            'orientation' => 'landscape',
            'download' => true,
            'filename' => 'Client_' . $id
        );
```

i hope this will help you,

Comment: setting  'engine' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',  this worked for me.. Thanks